# How to create stacked barchart using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to create stack bar chart using matplotlib using following code but the starting and ending point of second part is wrong

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 7
m = (5,10,30,40,0,0,0)      #(0-5,0-10,26-30,36-40)
w = (15,25,35,0,0,0,0)      #(11-15,16-25,31-35)
ind=[5,10 ,15 ,25 ,30,35,40] 
# the x locations for the groups
width = 0.55       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

p1 = plt.bar(ind, m, width, color='r')
p2 = plt.bar(ind, w, width, color='y',bottom=m)

plt.show()
```

but  `#(0-5,0-10,26-30,36-40)  #(11-15,16-25,31-35)`    bar chart plot on each other but i want first part would be 0 to 5 and second part will be 6 to 15 but it gives 5+15=20 that is wrong i don't want to join it. i mean if first part is 0-5 and second part is 6-15 so that it will show 0-5 and 6-15 not up to 5+15 = 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you don't really want a stacked bar chart, you want `w` to plot behind `m`. You can do this by setting the `zorder` of `m` to be lower than `w`:

```
p1 = plt.bar(ind, m, width, color='r',zorder=2)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, w, width, color='y',zorder=1)
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to keep the `bottom=m` option, you need to subtract `m` from `w`. First, you need to convert `m` and `w` to `numpy.array`. Then you could plot `p2` like this:

```
p2 = plt.bar(ind, np.maximum(w-m,0), width, color='y',bottom=m)
```

Note that you have to use `np.maximum` to prevent `w` going negative, for example when `m=40` and `w=0`.

Comment: thanks  this right I have one more question  I have some range for example     0-5  normal    6-10 normal  11-25 i trapping and again 26-35 normal how could i display this range an label on single bar with different colour but same category should have the same colour

Comment: I want this value on single bar not 2-3 bar with different colour and same category should be having same colour